# Start-Command PowerShell v3.0, does nothing

Tags: powershell

I am trying to install software (executable) on several servers with various versions of PowerShell.
Normally below code works with no issue on PS4 and up. On PS3 it does not install anything, nor does it produce any errors on the remove server eventviewer. It treated as success by printing out "... -- installation succeeded" and exits. I've googled about and read that perhaps Start-Process is the culprit in PS3.

```
Begin {
    $uncpath="\\remoteserveruncpath\"                                                      #"

    $exe_parameter1 = "centralserver.com"
    $creds = Get-Credential -Message "Password: " -Username "$($env:userdnsdomain)\$($env:username)"

}
Process {
    $dnshostname = "server1","server2","server3"

    ForEach ($server in $dnshostname) {
        Invoke-Command -ComputerName $server -ScriptBlock {
            param($server_int,$exe_parameter1_int,$uncpath_int,$creds_int)

            (New-Object -ComObject WScript.Network).MapNetworkDrive('Z:',"$($uncpath_int)", $false, "$($creds_int.Username)", "$($creds_int.GetNetworkCredential().Password)")

            $arguments = "/param_1=$exe_parameter1_int /param_2=$($server_int.ToLower()) /start-program=1 /S"

            If((Start-Process "Z:\installer.exe" -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait -Verb RunAs).ExitCode -ne 0) {
                Write-Host "$server_int -- installation succeeded"
            } else {
                Write-Error "$server_int -- installation failed"
            }
          } -ArgumentList $server,$exe_parameter1,$uncpath,$creds;
     }    
}
```

Any advice? Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without `-PassThru`, [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Start-Process) produces *no* output, so accessing `.ExitCode` effectively returns `$null`, always.

And since `$null -ne 0` is always `$true`, your code always indicates success.

In order to get the installer command's true exit code, you therefore need to use the following (note the addition of `-PassThru`):

```
if ((Start-Process -PassThru 'Z:\installer.exe' -ArgumentList $arguments -Wait -Verb RunAs).ExitCode -ne 0) { ... }
```